# Omniauth Facebook not returning email and gender rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth-facebook

I need to fetch name, email, image and gender from facebook. I am getting name and image, but email and gender is not fetched from facebook. I am struggling for past 2 days, can anyone help me out here.

User model:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|       
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.name = auth.info.name
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.gender = auth.extra.raw_info.gender #if user.gender.blank?
    user.image = auth.info.image        
    user.save!
  end
end
```

Omniauth.rb

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger    
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do

if Rails.env.production?
  provider :facebook, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SEC'
elsif Rails.env.development?
  provider :facebook, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SEC', {:scope => 'publish_actions,email', :client_options => { :ssl => { :ca_file => "#{Rails.root}/config/ca-bundle.crt" }}}
else  
  provider :facebook, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SEC'
end  
end
```

If I use `user.gender = auth.extra.raw.gender if user.gender.blank?` it returns a null.

Even I have checked with my facebook privacy settings it is in public profiles only. Can anyone please help me out here

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add these changes to get the data:

```
provider :facebook, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SEC_KEY', {:scope => 'email', :info_fields => 'email,name,first_name,last_name,gender', :client_options => { :ssl => { :ca_file => "#{Rails.root}/config/ca-bundle.crt" }}}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to have the `user_gender` scope now and have it approved by Facebook.

[image: facebook developers interface]

Then you can do something like:

```rb
    provider(
      :facebook,
      ENV.fetch("FACEBOOK_APP_ID"),
      ENV.fetch("FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET"),
      image_size: :large,
      secure_image_url: true,
      scope: "public_profile,email,user_gender",
      info_fields: "email,name,first_name,last_name,gender",
    )
```